# How to read two sheet from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have two sheets in CSV excel file which I upload using the following code. But from this code it reads only the first sheet. Even `httpRequest.Files.Count` returns only 1. How to read both sheet of the file

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                {
                    long dataSourceId = 1;
                    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + postedFile.FileName);
                    //postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                    Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
                    byte[] fileData = null;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(postedFile.InputStream))
                    {
                        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(postedFile.ContentLength);
                    }
                    Stream strrr = new MemoryStream(fileData);

                }
            }
```

Comment: You can't have two CSV sheets in excel.  Impossible.  A CSV file is a text file with only one sheet.

Comment: First CSV file is as comma seperated and different than excel file. So there is no concept of Shet1,Sheet2 in CSV file so it should be excel file , if so then ypou can read it from sheet name something like this                     

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SHEET1$", excelConnection);

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell CSV files aren't workbooks like Excel files, so you won't be about to read CSV file with two sheets as two entities on a single file. This is why I came to that conclusion:

http://network.ubotstudio.com/forum/index.php/topic/3236-save-in-multiple-sheets-in-a-csv-file/

You have two options: 1) Create multiple CSV files with the needed data and read from them individually OR 2) Use an Excel file that is formatted to handle these multiple sheet features.

Comment: First CSV file is as comma seperated and different than excel file. So there is no concept of Shet1,Sheet2 in CSV file so it should be excel file , if sp then ypou can read it from sheet name something like this     'DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SHEET!$", excelConnection);
            da.Fill(dataTable);'